# Highcharts, custom formatting for labels - xAxis

Tags: highcharts, label

I've just encountered a problem I could not find solution for, so that's the cause of my post.

I am using:

```
xAxis: {
     gridLineWidth: 0,
     type: 'datetime',
     labels: {
         useHTML: true,
         formatter: function() {
              return '<div class="labels" style="margin-top:20px;font-family:Open Sans;">' + $charts.convert_label_time(this.value) + '</div>';
         }
      }
},
```

After AJAX call labels are going to disappear and the "DIV" ('.highcharts-axis-labels') that is related to them is removed.

The cause of this reaction is - Adding dynamically series using

```
chart.addSeries();
```

Any tips?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle ?

Comment: What your $charts.convert_label_time(this.value) contains?, how your full chart looks like?